# join two tables from two database in cakephp

Tags: php

I have created two db and join two tables from two db. The query working in local but not working in live server and shows error like

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command
>   denied to user

and my code for join query :

```
$holiday_workings = $this->CompoffEntry->find('all', array(

            'joins' => array(
                    array(
                            'table' => 'Meds.employee_details',
                            'alias' => 'Emp_det',
                            'type'  => 'INNER',
                            'foreignKey'    => false,
                            'conditions'    => array('CompoffEntry.worked_on_period' => $holiday_period,'CompoffEntry.worked_on_date != ' => null,'CompoffEntry.employee_detail_id = Emp_det.employee_detail_id', 'Emp_det.emp_status = "A"',($department != 'all') ? 'Emp_det.department_id = '.$department : '',($roleId == 5) ? 'reporting_id = '.$user_id : ''),
                    ) 
            )
    ));
```

Comment: Error is pretty self explaining. "SELECT  command denied to user"

Answer (score 0):

When joining tables please try and use foreign keys to make your work simpler

```
SELECT * 
FROM Emp_det
JOIN table_1 ON CompoffEntry.employee_detail_id = Emp_det.employee_detail_id
WHERE Emp_det.emp_status = "A" 
AND 'Emp_det.department_id = '.$department : ''
AND ($roleId == 5) ? 'reporting_id = '.$user_id : ''
```

So longer as your variables are well initialized and assigned values the code should work as expected. Thank you.